# Confusion about MGFs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $A$ and $B$ are independent exponential $\lambda$ random variables, I know that the MGF of $A - B$ is $(\lambda^2)/(\lambda^2 - t^2).$ When I calculate $E[(A - B)^2]$ with this MGF, I get $0,$ but when I expand $E[(A - B)^2]$ and calculate it, I get $2/(\lambda^2).$ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, the issue seems to be about **how** you "calculate[d] $\mathbb{E}[(A-B)^2]$ with this MGF." Evaluating the second derivative at $0$ does give $2/\lambda^2$, maybe you made a calculation error?

Comment: @ClementC. I'm not quite sure how to calculate it- I found that the second derivative was 8(t^2)(lambda^2)/(lambda^2 - t^2)^3, and I evaluated this with t=0

Comment: This seems to be the issue -- the second derivative (for $|t| < \lambda$) is $$\frac{2\lambda^2(\lambda^2+3t^2)}{(\lambda^2-t^2)^3}$$
see, e.g.,
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5B%5C%5BLambda%5D%5E2%2F%28%5C%5BLambda%5D%5E2+-+t%5E2%29%2C+t%2C+t%5D

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\e}{\operatorname E}$
\begin{align}
M_A(t) = \e(e^{tA}) = \int_0^\infty e^{ta} e^{-\lambda a} (\lambda\,da) & = \frac\lambda{\lambda-t}. \\[8pt]
M_{-B}(t) = \e(e^{t(-B)}) = \int_0^\infty e^{t(-b)} e^{-\lambda b}(\lambda\,db)  & = \frac\lambda{\lambda+t}. \\[8pt]
M_{A-B}(t) = M_A(t)M_{-B}(t) & = \frac{\lambda^2}{\lambda^2-t^2}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
= \frac 1 {1 - (t/\lambda)^2} = {} & 1 + \left( \frac t \lambda \right)^2 + \left(\frac t \lambda\right)^4 + \cdots \\[8pt] 
& M''_{A-B}(0) = \frac 2 {\lambda^2}.
\end{align}